# Is `babel` the "de facto" package for managing locale settings?

Tags: babel

I am working on a package that could be use in different languages.

I'd like to delegate the standard language settings to `babel`, mainly the spacing around punctuation and the writing of dates.

Is it a bad idea to impose the loading of babel to manage local settings? The user could load `babel` before mine, such as to use `babel` fine-tuning before working with my package?

Comment: the two languare packages are babel and polyglossia. And it is up to you if you want to force your users to use babel or if you want to support both options.

Comment: The package `scrbase` (part of KoMa script) provides macros which can interact both with `babel` or `polyglossia`. Whether this might be useful to you depends however on what exactly you want to do, of which you have given no hint whatsoever...

Comment: @campa I have updated my question. I'm particularly interested in the managing of the spaces around punctuation and the writing dates.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way locale settings work is as follows:

- Language names are set either as package or class options. The latter are passed to packages, so it’s a convenient way to set it for several packages at once.
- With this info, packages take the required actions. This includes `babel`.

So, except if strictly necessary, I wouldn’t load `babel`, so that the user can choose what to do (even loading the alternative `polyglossia`, which has its own mechanism to load languages).

The `babel` manual lists the names of recognized languages.

Comment: My own private document class loads only hyphenation. No locale settings, except for a few I defined. So, no need to preload babel or polyglossia, as long as the language hyphenation is installed.